# run activex dll on php server

Tags: php, vba, dll, vb6, activex

can i compile a VBA macro from an excel file into an activex dll and load/run that from php on a linux shared hosting server, and if i convert a VBA macro into a VB6 activex dll will it run on a linux server

i have a few VBA macros from a 3rd party that needs to run and rearrange the columns in an excel file before my PHP script uses the result to update a database.

Comment: Could the columns be re-arranged from within your PHP script? i.e. can the logic of the VBA macro be rewritten in PHP?

Comment: it can, but there will be 100 or more different macros written by someone else, each excel fill is unique so it needs its own data converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not easily with a Linux server. You might be able to get something to work with [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/), but there's no real good way.

If it was running on a Windows machine, it might be possible.

Comment: Even then you'd probably need Excel installed to do what you're trying.  Excel isn't meant to run on a server.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: i dont think i can installing wine on a cheap shared web hosting, but would it be better to somehow download a macro and run it locally on the clients desktop, then have that macro upload the converted data, and ty bob, im no longer looking at automating excel on the server